# tfsec with tfvars file(.tfsec folder and tfvars file are present in different folder)

Tags: tfsec

I am doing static code analysis of my terraform file using tfsec, my .tfsec(contain custom check) and terraform.tfvars file are in different folder.

I can use "tfsec --tfvars-file terraform.tfvars" command if .tfsec folder and terraform.tfvars file present in same folder.

because .tfsec folder and terraform.tfvars file present in different folder so it is showing an error that terraform.tfvars file is not accessible.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `--tfvars-file` takes a _path_. Give it an absolute or relative path. How you do this depends on the command shell you are using and/or the OS. If you need help understanding command line pathnames for your environment, this is a different question that **you should research first**. Hint: this problem you are having has nothing to do with the `tfsec` executable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I got the solution. I have to give relative path.